# Closed form for sum of $\ln(x+2^n)/2^n$ from $n=1$ to $\infty$

Tags: summation, utility

Is there a closed form for the following sum, where $x>0$?
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\ln(x+2^n)}{2^n}$$

The sum pops up when considering the expected utility of a game where one receives $\$2^n$ if the first head occurs on the $n^{th}$ flip of a fair coin, where the utility function is $U(w)=\ln (w)$. I am not interested in convergence proofs, only closed form expressions.

Comment: I doubt it (but I don't see how to prove it).

Comment: You could get quite accurate *approximations*.